# How to deal with trolls entering wrong email addresses to mess with my SendGrid reputation?

Tags: email, email-address, email-accounts

My website sends emails to users via SendGrid, a transactional email delivery platform. SendGrid accounts have a reputation bar. When your emails bounce or get marked as spam, your reputation goes down. If your reputation goes below 70%, your account is subject to review.

There's a box on my site in which people can provide their email addresses. What if a troll enters nonexistent email addresses or email addresses that belong to other people? My site is new and unpopular (less than 10 views a day), so this behavior is sure to negatively affect my SendGrid reputation.

How do I manage these troublesome users?

Comment: Like if some cool kid puts a known [spam trap](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Deliver/Undeliverable_Email/spam_trapped.html) as their personal email on my site, I send an email to them, and then I'm blacklisted.

Comment: Double optin? If they don't have access to the particular email address then they won't be able to confirm their initial optin from that email address
https://sendgrid.com/blog/double-opt-in-3-helpful-tricks-to-confirm-your-subscribers/

Comment: 10 view per day, so let's say 1 new subscriber everyday. In 1 month you get 15 fake subscriber and 15 real. So here your reputation is 50%. Now again if you send emails(some informative) to those 15 real subscriber in 1 month then your reputation will jump to 75%. In short you can increase your reputation by sending emails to your real subscriber. Double optin like sending verification link is must for anyone.